# Python calculation of negative powers strange result

Tags: python, math

Does anyone know why the output of the bellow calculations returns different results, as it should be the same.

```
(-0.99)**(-0.99)
```

returns `(-1.0095011228760993-0.03172485085856595j)`

and

```
-0.99**-0.99
```

returns `-1.0099994966583417`

Comment: Due to the order of operations, the exponentiation is done before the first minus sign. Therefore the second calculation has an implied parenthesis in a different place (around everything except the first minus sign) than the explicit parenthesis of the first calculation (around  `-0.99`). This particular order of operations is the mathematical standard and is used in Python.

Comment: For more details on Python's order of operations (also called operator precedence), [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Note that exponentiation is lower in the table than "negative," so exponentiation is done before negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so let's assemble the partial answers that are elsewhere, and also provide more complete context.

First of all, the premise that these should be equivalent expressions is incorrect.  `-x**y` is *not* `(-x)**y` but rather is `-(x**y)`.

Admittedly this is odd.  If you write `-2` on paper, you likely think of the `-` as part of the number, rather than as an operator whose precedence could be questioned.  And yet if you write -2<sup>2</sup> it is standard to say this is -4, while (-2)<sup>2</sup> is of course 4.

Here is an article on the subject: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180224125142/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61633.html)

Anyway, that's the short answer as to why they're not the same expression.  Given that, it's just a matter of understanding each expression.

```
-.99**-.99
```

could be written

```
-1 * (.99**-.99)
-1 / (.99**.99)
```

The denominator can then be read "the hundredth root of .99 to the 99th power", and then it's just a matter of running through a pain-in-the-arse calculation.

On the other hand,

```
(-0.99)**(-0.99)
```

can also be simplified, but eventually we're going to take an even root of a negative number; so the answer must be a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

```
(-0.99)**(-0.99) yields a complex number, while -0.99**-0.99 yields a float.
```

Comment: You only restated that the two results are different. The questioner already knows that. The question is *why* those results are different.

Comment: For that I would point to your comment to the original question. :) Just wanted to add that the output types are different, too.